# How can I find company descriptions for a long list of companies?

Tags: data, scraping, crawling

I'm going to train an ml algorithm to qualify potential sales leads based upon company descriptions. To do this, I need to find the company descriptions programatically.

E.g. given a long list of company names, how can I find descriptions for these companies. Here are my current techniques, which works ok, but not great:

- Using Google Search API to and fetch summary from the results page (Google normally gives the company website as the first result when searching by company name)
- Fetch all data from the company's website (includes an about-page and a lot of other less relevant data)
- Using the FullContact Company API to get any descriptions the company has on its social profiles (works great if the company has an online precense)

Comment: Hi Welcome to DS.SE. Could you let us know which country you are in, that will help in knowing what companies you are interested in and a better answer

Comment: I think you would have better luck posting this question on opendata - http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What did you end up doing?